# SQL Server Non-Standard Date Based Histogram

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting, data-mining

I have user login data with timestamps and what I would like to do is get a histogram of logins by year, but with the year starting at an arbitrary date. For example, I want the following sort of information:

```
1 May 2005 - 30 Apr 2006 | 525
1 May 2006 - 30 Apr 2007 | 673
1 May 2007 - 30 Apr 2008 | 892
1 May 2006 - 30 Apr 2009 | 1047
```

The labels in the first column are not important, but the date ranges are. I know I can break it down by strait years with:

```
SELECT YEAR([date]) AS [year], COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM logins
GROUP BY YEAR([date])
ORDER BY [year]
```

But that doesn't give me the data ranges I want. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @baseDate datetime
set @baseDate = '1 May 2005'

SELECT
    datediff(year, @baseDate, [date]) AS YearBucket 
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM logins
GROUP BY datediff(year, @baseDate, [date])
ORDER BY datediff(year, @baseDate, [date])
```

EDIT - apologies, you are correct. Here is a fixed version (I should have used a test table to start with...)

```
create table logins (date datetime, foo int)
insert logins values ('1 may 2005', 1)
insert logins values ('1 apr 2006', 2)
insert logins values ('1 may 2006', 3)

declare @baseDate datetime
set @baseDate = '1 May 2005'

SELECT
    datediff(day, @baseDate, [date]) / 365 AS YearBucket 
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM logins
GROUP BY datediff(day, @baseDate, [date]) / 365
ORDER BY datediff(day, @baseDate, [date]) / 365
```

Change the datediff units if you want more granularity than days.

EDIT #2 - ok, here is a more robust solution that handles leap years :)
EDIT #3 - Actually this doesn't handle leap years, instead it allows for variable intervals of time to be specified. Go with dateadd(year, 1, @baseDate) for the leap year safe approach.

```
declare @baseDate datetime, @interval datetime
--@interval is expressed as time above 0 time (1/1/1900)
select @baseDate = '1 May 2005', @interval = '1901'

declare @timeRanges table (beginIntervalInclusive datetime, endIntervalExclusive datetime)
declare @i int
set @i = 1
while @i <= 10
begin
    insert @timeRanges values(@baseDate, @baseDate + @interval)
    set @baseDate = @baseDate + @interval
    set @i = @i + 1
end

SELECT
    tr.beginIntervalInclusive,
    tr.endIntervalExclusive,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM logins join @timeRanges as tr
    on logins.date >= tr.beginIntervalInclusive
        and logins.date < tr.endIntervalExclusive
GROUP BY  tr.beginIntervalInclusive, tr.endIntervalExclusive
ORDER BY  tr.beginIntervalInclusive
```

Comment: Gives the exact same results, just without the year in front.

Comment: @cdeszaq - you are right, sorry about that. Query is fixed now, I should have used a test table to start with..

Comment: :) I had just gotten to that myself...but will it handle leap years correctly, or will that introduce off-by-1 errors?

Comment: @cdeszaq - ok, here is a more robust solution :)

Comment: so close...still off by 1 for 1 jan 2005...end interval gets set to dec 31, rather than jan 1 of the next year for 2008

Comment: Got it...DATEADD(year,1, @baseDate) is needed instead of @baseDate + @interval

Comment: @cdeszaq - are you sure @baseDate + @interval isn't working? Eyeballing the contents of @timeRanges, it looks good to me. I'm not sure how 1/1/2005 fits in, my values define ranges for 5/1/2005 - 4/29/2015.

Comment: The interval was being incorrectly applied in the 2008 leap year, missing by 1 day, putting the ending interval 1 day short. I am guessing that the '+' operator on dates does not correctly handle leap years. The DATEADD function does seem to though.

Comment: @cdeszaq - ah I see, difference of expectation. You want a well defined 'year', I was on wrong track thinking that a variable interval of time would be more useful. I think the + shouldn't handle leap years since I'm adding the interval of 1900-1901 (which is a non-leap year). I see dateadd() with YEAR is more what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a way to define your date ranges in a separate table then select out a label and two columns of dates and join on that from your main query something like this depending on your tables.

```
Select Count(*) as NoLogons, DateRangeLabel
From logins a
inner join
(
Select
DateRangeLabel, StartDate, EndDate
From tblMyDates 
) b
on a.date between b.startdate and b.enddate
Group by DateRangeLabel
```